# Added UIImageView to UITableViewCell outside cell's bounds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm adding an `UIImageView` to my custom `UITableViewCell`. This image is then displayed outside the bounds of the cell. I've also added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the image so that when I tap on the image it will be removed from the view.

However when I tap on the image there is another cell beneath it that instead reacts on the tap. So it seems that adding a tap gesture recognizer to the image doesn't have any effect. And yes I have set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This image is then displayed outside the bounds of the cell." your view will not receive touches outside it's bounds therefore the subview will not receive touches if it's parent does not

Comment: So to achieve what I want to do I need to add the `UIImageView` to the  `UITableView` for it to be able to intercept touches?

Comment: Sounds like that should work. You may also want to look into `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`’s `-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`  to control whether your recognizer should fire its handler when it is potentially conflicting with one of the table’s or cells’ recognizers.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing what you are trying to achieve but adding views to the tableView does not sound like a great approach.

Comment: Like you said you could just add this view to the tableView, but you'll probably want to make sure that you disable/reenable the tableview scroll at different points to stop the ballon scrolling with it